# ByteArrayInputStream uploaded to S3 are encoded strangely?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, sdk

I want to upload an excel file to s3 with CSV type using Java SDK.
First I convert it to ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream.
After that I upload it to s3 with CSV type. Below is my code.

```
public boolean exportFileToS3(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exportFileToS3 error ", e);
    }
    
    //AWS Credential
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(mycredential))
            .withRegion(myregion)
            .build();
    
    // Setup data
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length);
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentType("text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);

    
    //Upload to S3
    String bucketName = "my bucket";
    String fileName = "test.csv"
    PutObjectResult putResult = s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, byteArrayInputStream, objectMetadata));
    byteArrayInputStream.close();
    return (putResult != null);
}
```

I successfully uploaded it to S3. But when I downloaded it from S3, I opened it by notepad or VSCode, it showed all strange characters that not like as my workbook. Like that: qfgfWｶqｶZCB|ﾃﾆ|ﾄ*・h羹・,^黠Va某K<4.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is not that the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is encoded strangely - the problem is that the method `XSSFWorkbook.write()` does not produce a CSV file, it produces a .xlsx file. If a .xlsx file meets your requirements then you just have to adjust the content type: `objectMetadata.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");`

Comment: If however you need a CSV file then you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283179/how-to-convert-xlsx-file-to-csv

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks for your comment. I will try this